# MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification does not fire [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm running into a problem with the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification notification.
I've regisered to recieve the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification notification and MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification but the first one never fires.
Is this bug in Firmware OS 3.0 ? maybe fixed in 3.1 ? or ? Because my divice and similator is 3.0 maybe this is a bug ?

My code :

```
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MovieDidLoad:) name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MovieDidLoad:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
...
-(void)MovieDidLoad:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Notification Listener" 
                          message:@"Notification Listener invoked" 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok dude!" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];   
    [alert show]; 
    [alert release];    

}
```

The MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is always fired but MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification is never fired.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085311/how-to-know-that-mpmovieplayercontroller-is-playing-in-iphone-os-3-0/2086944#2086944) with a workaround. It's not ideal but may be worth a look if no other solution can be found?