# how to know that MPMoviePlayerController is playing in Iphone OS 3.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to know if at an specific moment the MPMoviePlayerController is playing.

In iphone 3.0 it is not firing the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification.

Does anyone knows any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question (but no answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838681/mpmovieplayercontentpreloaddidfinishnotification-does-not-fire-iphone) and several other reports can be found on other sites (e.g. [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2071295))

Not ideal, but it seems targeting 3.1 solves the problem.

A workaround maybe to set the `MPMoviePlayerController` property `scalingMode` to something other than the default `MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit` ( e.g. `MPMovieScalingModeNone` and make sure your video is correct size) before calling `play` and then hook the `MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification` event instead. it seems to get called (more than once!) as soon as the movie starts playing. Of course it will also be called if the user changes the scaling mode manually, so code for this. It's dirty but may help you?

Comment: I can't tell all user to upgrade to 3.1. :(

Comment: edited my answer with possible workaround. I don;t like it but can't find anything else that works!

Answer (score 5):

So thanks for the answer.
I fix this so I will post the answer.
The answer is that MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification is NOT FIRED if you invoke play() right after the initialization.

To have MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification which works ok you have to invoke the "play()" method of the MPMoviePlayerController when the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification is fired ( I mean in the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification method ). In this case it always works.

Tested on 3.0, 3.1 and 3.1.2

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid because this answer has been upvoted 3 times- but how can I call the [.. play] method from the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification if the notification is never fired?  Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: I mean I don't call play beforehand and it still doesn't work